# GOOGLE ANALYTICS: UA Property Not Passing Event Data to GA4 Property

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, event-tracking

I'm working on setting up GA4 properties for some of my clients. I've noticed some of the UA properties that have events set up in Tag Manager are not passing event data to the GA4 property.

For reference, I updated the data stream settings in GA4 to collect UA events. The setting is located under admin>data streams>client website stream>additional settings>more tagging settings. (Screenshot below.)

I'm wondering why event data is not going into GA4? The client has events already set up in Tag Manager. However, the tag type is UA and not GA4. Should I set up an additional event in GTM with a GA4 tag for the same event action?

[Collect UA events setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKhnz.png)
[Current GTM Event Tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YS1RZ.png)

Answer (score 1):

The `collect universal analytics events` is only collecting the event from

`ga()` function, not from the Universal Analytic tag in the GTM.

I am afraid that you will need to set up the tags again  for all the events for GA4.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing, thank you!